# Serenity/jBehave - how to open current Serenity report when test is finished

Tags: selenium, jbehave, serenity-bdd

Using jbehave and serenity for reporting: How to pass code after the report is generated. Annontation `@AfterStories` is not helping, current one is generated after that. (I am not asking how to open any report, but how to do it to get **current** report, now I am opening previous one which is the latest in the target folder)

```java
@Managed
private WebDriver driver;

@BeforeStories
.....

@AfterStories
public void openLatestSerenityReport {
    myMethod.openLatestSerenityReport();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be non-trivial, as there is no built-in mechanism to do this. You might be able to use a JVM hook or write your own JUnit runner class to run the Serenity class itself.

Comment: Thx for suggestions, I have tried JVM hook, but it doens't allow to open any file, because this shutdown hook should not be used for some new actions or creation of new objects, more for cleaning up etc.. so at least I am loging the full link of report to log now, for easier reuse. But I am not giving up, will be looking for solution.